# How can I calculate the autocorrelation of a signal in Mathematica environment?

Tags: autocorrelation, mathematica

I tried `CorrelationFunction[Transpose[{data,data}]][[All,1,2]]` but it doesn't work! I mean the results are identical with those if I run `CorrelationFunction[data]`.

Comment: Note that the above result is not correct theoretically due to the finite size of the data. The result is known as the biased estimate. What you want is an "unbiased estimate."

Answer (score 6):

It's been a long since I didn't play with Mathematica, and I just had a quick look on Google, but can't you just use (here with some fake data)

```
x = Table[Sin[x] + 0.2 RandomReal[], {x, -4, 4, .1}];
ListPlot[x, DataRange -> {-4, 4}]
```

[image]

the function [ListCorrelate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListCorrelate.html)?

```
acf = ListCorrelate[x, x, {1, 1}, 0]
ListPlot[acf, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: tnx for the help.